# Protractor - how to run code in browser before angular loads

Tags: protractor

When running my automation tests I need to run code in my browser before angular is initialised.

I have tried the `mockModules` approach:

```
function setupBrowser(){
    console.log(`Setting up browser`);
}

browser.addMockModule('someRandomStringNotAModuleName', setupBrowser );

browser.get('myAppUrl');
```

but I never see the `setting up browser` message in the browser console. I imagine that this is because I am not trying to mock an angular module, I am just trying to execute code before my app boots.

Is there an alternate way of doing this?

I need to run this code after I have navigated to my angular app but before angular boots because I am listening for `start` and `stop` messages from my app. I have a function that waits for `stop` messages. If there has been no `start` message it returns immediately.

If I can't run code before angular boots I can't be sure that I have captured all `start` messages correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your automation tests will not start unless it encounters the onPrepare segment in your configuration file. If you want any code to execute before your browser starts executing your tests, onPrepare is the place to put it.

If you want to execute something before the browser even starts, you will have to add a script that executes the functionality you require and add it to the package.json "script" to execute before your protractor conf.js executes.

Comment: That will run before all tests start and also before I load any pages I to the browser. I need to execute code in the browser after I have navigated to my app page and before angular bootstrap